# Update values in a MySQL table instead of adding new ones

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a way for a user to submit team scores through an HTML form, and store those values in a MySQL table to read back later.

The issue (besides that I am finding random code online) is that I need each instance of the score (Score1, Score2, Score3, etc) to just update its value. So if a new score is added for "Score1" it should replace the old score. Right now it's just creating rows with each new submission listed.

So here is what I was able to put together so far. This is the form that will be duplicated roughly 200 times (I have 200 scores to insert):

```
<form action="storage.php" id="scores" method="post">
   <input type="number" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" name="score" id="score1">
```

Then my storage.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
    $host     = "localhost"; // Host name 
    $username = "scoreboard"; // Mysql username 
    $password = "XXXX"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name  = "admin_scoreboard"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "scores"; // Table name 
    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
    // Get values from form 
    $score1 = $_POST['score1'];
    // Insert data into mysql 
    $sql    = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(score1)VALUES('$score1')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
    if ($result) {
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='test.html'>Back to main page</a>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
?>
```

In case this is confusing, my overall goal is to have coaches submit scores for their teams through an HTML form, store that in MySQL, and then display the scores in an HTML table late. But yeah, the main thing is to have the coaches go back and update the scores for the particular team if needed. I'll worry about pulling the data back from MySQL at another time :)

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You need to look up the UPDATE sql command

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer would involve a tutorial session and SO is not a Tutorial Site

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't mean to have you "code for me". I was obviously tasked with a project that is out of my league. I'll take a look at some of these resources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Answer (score 0):

QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name="A", age=19
```

try like this..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with this one

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name(score1) VALUES('$score1') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score1='$score1'
```